# How to access Stateful widget variable inside State class outside the build method?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to access the 'updateNotesModel' variable declared in the code in the _UpdateNotesState. I found out that you can do it using the 'widget' keyword as shown in the Scaffold below. But the problem here is that I am trying to access the variable outside the build method in order to give the TextEditingController a default value. How can I achieve this?

```
class UpdateNotes extends StatefulWidget {

  final NotesModel updateNotesModel;
  UpdateNotes({Key key, this.updateNotesModel}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _UpdateNotesState createState() => _UpdateNotesState();
}

class _UpdateNotesState extends State<UpdateNotes> {

  TextEditingController _titleController = 
new TextEditingController(text: widget.updateNotesModel.someValue); //getting an error
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    var a = widget.updateNotesModel.someValue
     .
     .
     .
     )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it in `initState`:

```
class _UpdateNotesState extends State<UpdateNotes> {
  TextEditingController _titleController = new TextEditingController(); 

  @override
  void initState() {
    _titleController.text= widget.updateNotesModel.someValue;
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution! Just one more thing, is there a way through which I can maybe change updateNotesModel member's value even though flutter forces me to initialize it as final. Like widget.updateNotesModel.someValue = newValue?

Comment: It is ok. This variable shouldn't be const in parent widget. You can `setState`  in a parent widget and then flutter rebuild widget tree and reinitialize your widget.

Comment: Or if you wont change it in this widget you should make `updateNotesModel` part of state, not widget.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll give it a try and hopefully I can figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use the `late` keyword. From [the docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#late-variables):

> Dart 2.12 added the `late` modifier, which has two use cases:
>
> - Declaring a non-nullable variable that’s initialized after its declaration.
> - Lazily initializing a variable.

```dart
class _UpdateNotesState extends State<UpdateNotes> {
  late TextEditingController _titleController = new TextEditingController(text: widget.updateNotesModel.someValue);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that unfortunately cannot be done as, widget keyword cannot be accessed while initializing

Comment: The accepted answer from two years ago suggests it can be done. Is that answer wrong?

Comment: @JeremyCaney I think what he means is we cannot access `widget`'s variable inside State class, outside the build method, or any other method.